# How open outlook on click on mailto instead of gmail etc

Tags: outlook, mailto

I want to open Outlook when anyone clicks on mailto: link, normally it is opening other options as well, but i want to open outlook only, 
moreover please also let me know what will happen if outlook is not installed ?

Thanks and Regards;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mailto` link will try to open the default email client on the user computer. If it is Outlook, it will be Outlook, but if it is Thunderbird, it will be Thunderbird.

Comment: is there any other way using javascript or anything thing else to launch only outlook please?